# Jackson Parsing Error

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, kotlin

I have a Kotlin data class that looks something like this

```
@Type("event")
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.KebabCaseStrategy::class)
open class Event(
        @PrimaryKey
        @Id(IntegerIdHandler::class)
        var id: Int? = null,
        var identifier: String? = null,
        var name: String? = null,
        var latitude: Double? = null,
        var longitude: Double? = null,
        var locationName: String? = null,
        var startsAt: String? = null,
        var endsAt: String? = null,
        var timezone: String? = null,
        var description: String? = null,
        var logoUrl: String? = null,
        var organizerName: String? = null,
        var organizerDescription: String? = null,
        var ticketUrl: String? = null,
        var privacy: String? = null,
        var type: String? = null,
        var topic: String? = null,
        var subTopic: String? = null,
        var codeOfConduct: String? = null,
        var email: String? = null,
        var schedulePublishedOn: String? = null,
        var searchableLocationName: String? = null,
        var state: String? = null,
        var isSessionsSpeakersEnabled: Boolean = false,
        var thumbnailImageUrl: String? = null,
        var originalImageUrl: String? = null,
        var largeImageUrl: String? = null,
        var iconImageUrl: String? = null,
        var createdAt: String? = null,
        var deletedAt: String? = null,
        @Relationship("event-copyright")
        var eventCopyright: Copyright? = null,
        @Relationship("speakers-call")
        var speakersCall: SpeakersCall? = null,
        @Relationship("social-links")
        var socialLinks: RealmList<SocialLink>? = null
) : RealmObject() {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false
        if (other !is Event) return false

        if (id != other.id) return false
        if (identifier != other.identifier) return false
        if (name != other.name) return false
        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id ?: 0
        result = 31 * result + (identifier?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + (name?.hashCode() ?: 0)

        return result
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Event(id=$id, identifier=$identifier, name=$name)"
    }

}
```

I am using Jackson as a Mapper to map my JSON into this Event model.
In the model, there is a property `isSessionsSpeakersEnabled`. The equivalent JSON property key is `"is-sessions-speakers-enabled"`. The given class mapping was perfectly fine when the model was written in Java but as soon as I converted it into Kotlin, the Naming Strategy used apparently changes the `isSessionsSpeakersEnabled` into `"sessions-speakers-enabled"` instead of `"is-sessions-speakers-enabled"`. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using @JsonProperty ?

Comment: I don't want to use the @JsonProperty. That's why the naming strategy exists to have a common naming for every field

Comment: @SriramR, yes that is indeed why naming strategies exist, but the reason why annotations such as `@JsonProperty` exist is because the naming strategy might not always match your use-case perfectly. `@JsonProperty` is the simple, straight-forward answer to your question; otherwise you might as well revert your class back to Java.

Comment: But here the naming strategy fits my use case perfectly. The field names were same in java as in kotlin. So the naming strategy should work exactly the same like it did in java

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is wondering how to fix it without adding too much boilerplate,

This error occurred because Kotlin removes the "is" in front of all getter methods generated. This hence caused my parsing problem because my json contained the "is" prefix. So I needed to use `@JsonProperty` here.

But if I add `@JsonProperty()` to one field, I will have to add `@JsonProperty()` to every field and that is just messy. So I added
`@field:JsonProperty()` instead. This enabled me to get my required functionality without adding much boilerplate to the code and the NamingStrategy took care of rest of the fields.

I hope this is clear.